# EMI Signature in electronics

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, filter, emi-filtering

What do we mean by **EMI Signature**? (Both theoretically and physically speaking)

Comment: This is a very broad subject. What do you understand by EMI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you fill out a form and *sign* the document at the end with a pen, for instance, the graphical characteristics of your "drawing" - the *signature* - identify you as the author.

In power electronics, but also in other domains, a *signature* is a specific set of characteristics (voltage, current, frequency etc.) which let you identify a behavior, a type of converter, a specific source etc. For instance, the drain-source ringing occurring in the primary-side of a flyback converter after the secondary diode has stopped conducting represents the typical *signature* of a converter operated in discontinuous conduction mode or DCM that you can observe with an oscilloscope:

[image]

What is of interest for the designer is the harmonic content of the converter operated in this mode: what is its electromagnetic interference (EMI) *signature* is what matters to dimension and size the front-end filter. What frequency dominates the response and how much shall it be attenuated are design criteria.

The equivalent circuit to determine the signature of a typical converter requires a line impedance stabilization network (a LISN) which sets the source output impedance to 50 ohms along a certain frequency range (10 kHz to 150 kHz). If you connect the switching converter to this LISN, you will obtain a frequency spectrum linking the current signature with its specific *EMI signature*. This is excerpted from an [application note](http://www.icbase.com/pdf/add/on/AN-106-00003en.pdf) I wrote when releasing the NCP1200 in 2000:

[image]

This EMI signature, which is the EMI spectrum (conducted or radiated) generated by a specific converter in a particular operating conditions (input and output) will tell you what compensation strategy to adopt to pass the standard you target (CISPR 22 or EN55022 for instance). Below is the typical EMI signature of a 100-kHz flyback converter:

[image]

From this signature, you see a second harmonic at 200 kHz delivering 90 dBµV. If you want to pass the limit with some margin, you will have to size your filter so that it attenuates at least by 30 dB at 200 kHz.

Answer (score 1):

It's a term that is similar to what the "listening operators" in submarines used. The operators could tell by listening what sort of boat was in the vicinity just by the sound of the acoustics transmitted through the sea.

In that respect each surface boat had a recognizable "acoustic signature" and, operators could not only distinguish between a destroyer and another type of warship but, a lot of the time they could distinguish between destroyer A and destroyer B of the same class.

Each boat has an acoustic signature and, with such devices as switch-mode power supplies, one design will have a different EMI signature to another due to different operating characteristics such as PWM frequency, load current, whether it uses spread-spectrum EMI reduction techniques.

Quite possibly it would be feasible to detect whether two otherwise identical devices used a different common-mode filter on the incoming AC power lines.

Comment: And now I'm getting all kind of ridiculous images in my head. Some guy at a test house sitting outside an EMC chamber, staring intently at a spec: "It is an Arduino Uno, Sir." His boss: "Are you sure? Could it be a Due?"  "No Sir, it's running 16MHz, I can tell by the third harmonic."  "Lord have mercy on us... Load the damped sinusoidal, 50V/m! Ferrite beads at the ready! Prepare for overtime, boys."

Comment: Aha(!) humour @Lundin